# Heroku Connect with Cakephp v3.0.12

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, heroku

I am trying to save data to Heroku Postgres which is also using for heroku connect with Salesforce.

I have an error that says

```
 Error:  [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 
 ERROR:  function   get_xmlbinary() does not exist
 LINE 1: SELECT (get_xmlbinary() = 'base64')

 HINT:   No function matches the given name and argument types. 
         You might need to add explicit type casts.

 QUERY:  SELECT (get_xmlbinary() = 'base64')
 CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function hc_contact_status() line 3 at 
          IF Request URL: /signup
```

and it's stack trace is

```
 #0 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php(169): PDOStatement->execute(NULL)
 #1 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php(274): Cake\Database\Statement\StatementDecorator->execute()
 #2 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Query.php(176): Cake\Database\Connection->run(Object(Cake\ORM\Query))
 #3 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1516): Cake\Database\Query->execute()
 #4 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1436): Cake\ORM\Table->_insert(Object(App\Model\Entity\Contact), Array)
 #5 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1367): Cake\ORM\Table->_processSave(Object(App\Model\Entity\Contact), Object(ArrayObject))
 #6 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php(561): Cake\ORM\Table->Cake\ORM\{closure}(Object(Cake\Database\Connection))
 #7 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1368): Cake\Database\Connection->transactional(Object(Closure))
 #8 app/src/Controller/ContactController.php(126): Cake\ORM\Table->save(Object(App\Model\Entity\Contact))
 #9 [internal function]: App\Controller\ContactController->signup('signup')
 #10 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(412): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
 #11 /app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(114): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
 #12 app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\ContactController))
 #13 app/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
 #14 {main}
```

Database block in my app.php is

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className'  => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver'     => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host'       => '[ host name for the heroku postgre ]',
        'port'       => '5432',
        'username'   => '[ user name for the heroku postgre ]',
        'password'   => '[ password for the heroku postgre ]',
        'database'   => '[ database for the heroku postgre ]',
        'encoding'   => 'utf8',
        'timezone'   => 'UTC',
        'schema'     => 'salesforce',             
        'cacheMetadata' => false,
        'log'        => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ],
```

In this setting, I can retrieve data from Heroku connect but when I try to write something in DB, it will return the error I showed above.

I found an Q and A made for Lavera user and I think I have the same situation. 
https://discussion.heroku.com/t/heroku-connect-with-laravel/1335

I think Schema => 'salseforce' need to be 'public' 
but I don't know how to change the setting in CakePHP environment.

I have also run

```
# set search_path=salesforce, public;
```

If anybody knows a solution for the CakePHP, Please let me know. 
I appreciate your help

Update:

I got respond from Heroku support and they gave me a good idea to solve this question.

Following are heroku's respond and tip

Why this happened ?

```
    this error is usually a result of an application incorrectly setting
 search_path and ignoring the public schema. Running set search_path   
 salesforce,public in psql only sets it for the current session.
```

How to possibly resolve this question ?

```
   Datasources:default:schema => 'public' rather than salesforce and then
use fully qualified table names elsewhere in your application.
```

or

```
    you could set schema => 'salesforce,public'
```

Note that he wasn't professional for CakePHP environment so He doesn't sure if second method works or not.

but I think I can do the first method.

If you have more idea of it or something to share on this topic please comment on below

Comment: Glad you solved it. The thing to do now is to post your solution below, as an answer to your own question, so that it no longer shows up in the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: And please remove "Solved" from your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Additional Update & Solution]

I just tried what the heroku support said. 
I edited a constructor in a Model like following 
(in my case, I did contact model )

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    // added "salesforce" for following table name 
    $this->table('salesforce.account');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

}
```

and 
In the app.php file

```
'schema'     => 'public',
```

Schema points to public.

This worked!